# Deleting certain objects in background from UITableViewCell With Swift and Parse

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

So I have a `UITableViewCell` and I want to delete the image from the tableView. But I also want to delete the given object from the Parse database.

I have the image object saved in the online Parse framework and in the `Local Datastore`.

```
for i in images{

  var imageNames = i.thumbnailImage
  var imageFile = PFFile(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageNames))

  //Pin the objects here!!
  var imageObject = PFObject(className: "img")
  imageObject["theImg"] = imageFile
  //imageObject["user"] = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
  imageObject.pinInBackgroundWithName("imgs")

  var objID = imageObject.objectId
  imageObject.pinInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
    if error == nil{

      println("Object Saved!!")
      imageObject.save()
      println(objID)
      self.imagesFromParse.append(imageNames!)

      self.tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
      println(error)
    }
})
```

I then have the delete `UITableViewCell` function called here -

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var cell:nudeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! nudeCell

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete{

        if self.imagesFromParse.count >= 1{

            self.imagesFromParse.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

           //Here is where i want to delete the object from the localDatastore and the online framwork
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to delete the object in the background. I do not know how to get the specific object ID in the given indexPath to delete.

Comment: The comment `//Here is where...` takes the place of the code that isn't working?  That is exactly the code the question needs to include.  Incidentally, I don't think you need the objectId to delete the object.

Comment: Why are you storing only the imageName in the imagesFromParse instead of the actual object, if you store the object you'd have the imageName and the image as part of the object, also the ID..

Comment: however when the tableView reloads the image that I deleted comes back @danh

Comment: @Jay the imageName variable is actually a PFFile that is going to Parse